# substitute '=' sign when an integer is encountered using python

Tags: python, regex, substring

Hi I am new to python and regex. I have a string which i want to reformat/substitute

```
string = '1John Radcliffe Hospital/Oxford/United Kingdom, 11Ruhr-Universität 
3/Bochum/Bochum/Germany, 3University of British Columbia/Vancouver/Canada, 4National 
Institute of Neuroscience, National Center of Neurology and Psychiatry/Tokyo/Japan, 
5University of Catania/Catania/Italy, 6F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd/Basel/Switzerland, 7 
University of Colorado School of Medicine/Aurora/United States of America'
```

i did try with:

```
re.sub('(, \d+()?)', r'\1=', string).strip()
```

Expected output:

```
string = '1=John Radcliffe Hospital/Oxford/United Kingdom, 11=Ruhr-Universität 
3/Bochum/Bochum/Germany, 3=University of British Columbia/Vancouver/Canada, 4=National 
Institute of Neuroscience, National Center of Neurology and Psychiatry/Tokyo/Japan, 
5=University of Catania/Catania/Italy, 6=F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd/Basel/Switzerland, 
7=University of Colorado School of Medicine/Aurora/United States of America'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can match either the start of the string, or a space and comma without using a capture group and assert not a digit after matching a single digit.

```
(?:^|, )\d+(?!/)
```

The pattern matches

- `(?:^|, )` Non capture group, assert either the start of the string or moatch `,`
- `\d+(?!/)` Match 1+ digits asserting not a `/` directly to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/m9rRgT/1) | [Python demo](https://ideone.com/HqI5oN)

In the replacement use the full match followed by an equals sign

```
\g<0>=
```

Example

```
import re

string = ("1John Radcliffe Hospital/Oxford/United Kingdom, 11Ruhr-Universität \n"
          "3/Bochum/Bochum/Germany, 3University of British Columbia/Vancouver/Canada, 4National \n"
          "Institute of Neuroscience, National Center of Neurology and Psychiatry/Tokyo/Japan, \n"
          "5University of Catania/Catania/Italy, 6F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd/Basel/Switzerland, 7 \n"
          "University of Colorado School of Medicine/Aurora/United States of America")

result = re.sub(r'(?:^|, )\d+(?!/)', r'\g<0>=', string, 0, re.MULTILINE).strip()
print(result)
```

Output

```
1=John Radcliffe Hospital/Oxford/United Kingdom, 11=Ruhr-Universität 
3/Bochum/Bochum/Germany, 3=University of British Columbia/Vancouver/Canada, 4=National 
Institute of Neuroscience, National Center of Neurology and Psychiatry/Tokyo/Japan, 
5=University of Catania/Catania/Italy, 6=F. Hoffmann-La Roche Ltd/Basel/Switzerland, 7= 
University of Colorado School of Medicine/Aurora/United States of America
```

Another option could be using a positive lookahead to assert an uppercase char `[A-Z]` after matching a digit.

```
(?:^|, )\d+(?=\s*[A-Z])
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/MxgiNj/1)

Comment: based on the above solution if you notice the output is 1=1Ruhr-Universität 
3=/Bochum/Bochum/Germany, 3=University of British Columbia/Vancouver/Canada, which is not what i want

Comment: @SouravSingh I see, I have updated the answer.

Comment: @SouravSingh You are welcome. If you also want to remove optional spaces after the number you can use `((?:^|, )\d+)(?!/)\s*` and replace with group 1 like `\g<1>=` See https://ideone.com/OAyHvu